# Firebase deferred deeplinks and Facebook Ads

Tags: ios, facebook, firebase, deeplink

I'm truing to use our firebase deferred deeplinks with facebook ads, but when i paste that link facebook ads manager shows "App Links Field Invalid:: The described URL doesn't have app links HTML meta tags. Use a different URL or a mobile deep link (e.g. "mobileapp://")."

[image]

How to make it work?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. We used Branch in the past and the links worked fine with Facebook but almost nothing in the SDK worked right. Did you find a solution for Firebase links?

Comment: Any luck anyone on this? I'm having similar issue

Comment: Still facing this issue and there's no solution on the internet to this......